# Force sender to include transaction fee

Tags: transaction-fees, satoshidice

According to this article [Instant Transaction Fraud: An Explanation](http://bitcoinmagazine.com/2960/instant-transaction-fraud-an-explanation/), SatoshiDice required all incoming transactions to include fees.  How do they do that?  I assume that they check the "fee" data from the gettransaction() call to the Bitcoin API.  But what happens if the user does not include a fee?  Does SatoshiDice reject the bet and send the bitcoins back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They simply do not process transactions they receive without a fee. The sender loses their coins to SatoshiDice if they make this mistake.